# Issue with navigation bar in child theme

Tags: customization, themes, child-theme

I have created a child theme of the evolve theme. The evolve theme was not edited before localy and was just downloaded from the [offical site](https://de.wordpress.org/themes/evolve/).

**functions.php** of child theme:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

**style.css** of child theme:

```
/*
Theme Name:   evolve Child
Theme URI:    [http://example.com/parent-theme/]
Description:  evolve Child Theme
Author:       Michael
Author URI:   [http://deinedomain.at]
Template:     evolve
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:         evolve,child
Text Domain:  evolve -child
*/
```

After activating the child the in the wordpress ui, the arrow of the navigation bar was crashed (please look screenshot):

[broken navigation bar in child theme](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C1bL_pW-T5A90pMdZ8ikRdqQHx3MSfD0/view)

[navigation bar in standard theme](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKQPOClFP8u8KGrlmewNryHEkWLipu3u/view)

Can you tell me how this could occur and can I somehow fix this issue?
I’m very new at wordpress, so I hope the informations in my questions are correct and complete. Please refer if you need more informations.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: hard to say without being able to look at the actual page. Can you share a link?

Comment: in your browser, hit f12 to inspect the page, find the element and look at what CSS is effecting each

Comment: Thank you @RiddleMeThis for the idea to inspect the page.

After adding the (exact same) code for the breadcrumb from the original style.css to the style.css of my child theme it worked. I wonder if this is the best solution, but I think it's a good workaround